# PHP Class: Not inserting data: Second Query

Tags: php, class, pdo

I have a class called contacts.  In this class I have a method called addContact().  The first statement execute correct, but it seems like it does not get the $db->lastInsertId().  Need some help please.  Here is my code:

```
        public function addContact($addcontactfirstname,$addcontactmiddlename,$addcontactlastname,$addcontactstreetnumber, $addcontactstreetname, $addcontactsuburb, $addcontactcity, $addcontactemailhome, $addcontactemailwork,$addcontacthomephone, $addcontactcellphone, $addcontactworkphone){
        $addsuccessfully = true;
        $addcontact_id = 0;

        try {
            $db = database::databaseConnect();

            $stmt1 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO personalinfo (firstname, middlename, lastname) VALUES (:addcontactfirstname, :addcontactmiddlename, :addcontactlastname)');
            $stmt1->bindParam(':addcontactfirstname', $addcontactfirstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt1->bindParam(':addcontactmiddlename', $addcontactmiddlename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt1->bindParam(':addcontactlastname', $addcontactlastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $successful1 = $stmt1->execute();
            $addcontact_id = $db->lastInsertId();

            if($successful1){
                //$addcontact_id = $db->lastInsertId();
                $successful1 = true;

                $stmt2 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO contactinfo (contact_id, streetnumber, streetname, suburbname, cityname, emailhome, emailwork, homephone, cellphone, workphone) VALUES (:addcontact_id, :addcontactstreetnumber, addcontactstreetname, :addcontactsuburb, :addcontactcity, :addcontactemailhome, :addcontactemailwork,:addcontacthomephone, :addcontactcellphone, :addcontactworkphone)');
                $stmt2->bindParam(':addcontact_id', $addcontact_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':addcontactstreetnumber', $addcontactstreetnumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':addcontactstreetname', $addcontactstreetname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':addcontactsuburb', $addcontactsuburb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':addcontactcity', $addcontactcity, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':addcontactemailhome', $addcontactemailhome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':addcontactemailwork', $addcontactemailwork, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':addcontacthomephone', $addcontacthomephone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':addcontactcellphone', $addcontactcellphone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':addcontacthomephone', $addcontactworkphone, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $successful2 = $stmt2->execute();

                if($successful2){
                    $successful2 = true;
                }

                if(!$successful1 && !$successful2){
                    $addsuccessfully = false;
                }

            }

            if($successful1 === true && $successful2 === true){
                $addsuccessfully = true;
            }
        } 

        catch (PDOException $e) {
            $addsuccessfully = false;
        }

        return $addsuccessfully;
    }
```

I have a function that I call from my view page.  Here is my function:

```
     function addContact($addcontactfirstname,$addcontactmiddlename,$addcontactlastname,$addcontactstreetnumber, $addcontactstreetname, $addcontactsuburb, $addcontactcity, $addcontactemailhome, $addcontactemailwork,$addcontacthomephone, $addcontactcellphone, $addcontactworkphone){
     global $addsuccessfully;
     contacts::addContact($addcontactfirstname,$addcontactmiddlename,$addcontactlastname,$addcontactstreetnumber, $addcontactstreetname, $addcontactsuburb, $addcontactcity, $addcontactemailhome, $addcontactemailwork,$addcontacthomephone, $addcontactcellphone, $addcontactworkphone);
     return $addsuccessfully;
 }
```

And here is my page where I call the function.  The page do say that the contact could not be added.  I know the first query works as it the contact shows in the database, but it does not add the second bit into the contactinfo table of the database.  Here is my view page:

```
<?php
/*The first thing that need to take place on this page is to ensure that the $admin value = 1.
 * If the value is not 1 the user will get redirected to the home page.  If the value of
 * $admin = null, it then indicates that the user is not logged in.  The system will then tell the
 * user that he need to logon first, but also warn the user that if he is not an admin user he won't be
 * allowed access to this page.  This is to ensure that the user don't type the url address in 
 * his browser to try and access this page.  This means that only admin users will be able to 
 * view this page while logged on and will be able to add new users.  This will be an admin
 * protected page.  Protcted so the user must be logged in and and admin user.
 */
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'functions/functions.php';
checkLoggedIn(page::ADDCONTACT); 

echo $message;

if ($pageID == 1){
    require_once 'includes/adminmenu.php';

    if($_POST){
        $addcontactfirstname = $_POST['addcontactfirstname'];
        $addcontactmiddlename = $_POST['addcontactmiddlename'];
        $addcontactlastname = $_POST['addcontactlastname'];
        $addcontactstreetnumber = $_POST['addcontactstreetnumber'];
        $addcontactstreetname = $_POST['addcontactstreetname'];
        $addcontactsuburb = $_POST['addcontactsuburb'];
        $addcontactcity = $_POST['addcontactcity'];
        $addcontactemailhome = $_POST['addcontactemailhome'];
        $addcontactemailwork = $_POST['addcontactemailwork'];
        $addcontacthomephone = $_POST['addcontacthomephone'];
        $addcontactcellphone = $_POST['addcontactcellphone'];
        $addcontactworkphone = $_POST['addcontactworkphone'];
        $errors = array();
        $homephonelength = false;
        $cellphonelength = false;
        $workphonelength = false;
        //$addsuccessfully = true;


        stripUserInput($addcontactfirstname,$addcontactmiddlename,$addcontactlastname,$addcontactstreetnumber,$addcontactstreetname,$addcontactsuburb,$addcontactcity,$addcontactemailhome,$addcontactemailwork,$addcontacthomephone,$addcontactcellphone,$addcontactworkphone);

        if(empty($addcontactfirstname)){
            $errors[] = 'First name can\'t be empty!';
        }

        if(empty($addcontacthomephone) && empty($addcontactcellphone) && empty($addcontactworkphone)){
            $errors[] = 'You must enter at least one telephone number!';
        }             

        if(!empty($addcontacthomephone)){
            //$phonenumber = $addcontacthomephone;
            $homephonelength = chechPhoneLenght($addcontacthomephone);

            if($homephonelength === true){
                $errors[] = 'The home phone number you entered is too short!';
            }
        }

        if(!empty($addcontactcellphone)){
            //$phonenumber = $addcontactcellphone;
            $cellphonelength = chechPhoneLenght($addcontactcellphone);

            if($cellphonelength === true){
                $errors[] = 'The mobile phone number you entered is too short!';
            }
        }

        if(!empty($addcontactworkphone)){
            //$phonenumber = $addcontactworkphone;
            $workphonelength = chechPhoneLenght($addcontactworkphone);

            if($workphonelength === true){
                $errors[] = 'The work phone number you entered is too short!';
            }
        }            

        if(!empty($addcontactemailhome)){
            $email = $addcontactemailhome;
            is_valid_email($email);

            if (is_valid_email($email) === false){
                $errors[] = 'You have entered an invalid home email address!';
            }
        }

        if(!empty($addcontactemailwork)){
            $email = $addcontactemailwork;
            is_valid_email($email);

            if(is_valid_email($email) === false){
                $errors[] = 'You have entered an invalid work email address!';
            }
        }

        if(empty($errors)){
            //Add the contact
            $addsuccessfully = addContact($addcontactfirstname,$addcontactmiddlename,$addcontactlastname,$addcontactstreetnumber, $addcontactstreetname, $addcontactsuburb, $addcontactcity, $addcontactemailhome, $addcontactemailwork,$addcontacthomephone, $addcontactcellphone, $addcontactworkphone);

            if($addsuccessfully === true){
                echo 'New contact added successfully!';
            }else{

                echo 'New contact could not be add.  Please go <a href="addcontact.php">back</a> and try again!';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<b>Please fix the following errors and try again!</b><br>';
            foreach ($errors as $key => $error_message){
                echo '<font color="red"><em>' . $error_message . '</font></em><br>';
            }
            ?>

            <h1>Add new contact</h1>
            <p><em>Fields marked with <font color="red">*</font> must be completed.</em></p>
            <form action="addcontact.php" method="post">
                <table cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>First name:</b> <font color="red">*</font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactfirstname" value="<?php echo $addcontactfirstname; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Middle name:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactmiddlename" value="<?php echo $addcontactmiddlename; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Last name:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactlastname" value="<?php echo $addcontactlastname; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Street number:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactstreetnumber" value="<?php echo $addcontactstreetnumber; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Street name:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactstreetname" value="<?php echo $addcontactstreetname; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Suburb:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactsuburb" value="<?php echo $addcontactsuburb; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>City:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactcity" value="<?php echo $addcontactcity; ?>" />
                        </td>              
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Email (H):</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactemailhome" value="<?php echo $addcontactemailhome; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Email (W):</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactemailwork" value="<?php echo $addcontactemailwork; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <font color="blue"><em><b>NOTE:</b> You must enter at least one telephone number.</em><br>  The number must include the area code e.g 065553322!</font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Phone (H):</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontacthomephone" value="<?php echo $addcontacthomephone; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Mobile:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactcellphone" value="<?php echo $addcontactcellphone; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Phone (W):</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="addcontactworkphone" value="<?php echo $addcontactworkphone; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right">
                            <input type="submit" value="Add contact" value="<?php echo $addcontactfirstname; ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>


            <?php
        }

    }else{

    ?>

    <h1>Add new contact</h1>
    <p><em>Fields marked with <font color="red">*</font> must be completed.</em></p>
    <form action="addcontact.php" method="post">
        <table cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>First name:</b> <font color="red">*</font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactfirstname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Middle name:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactmiddlename" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Last name:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactlastname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Street number:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactstreetnumber" />
                </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Street name:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactstreetname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Suburb:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactsuburb" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>City:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactcity" />
                </td>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Email (H):</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactemailhome" />
                </td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Email (W):</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactemailwork" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <font color="blue"><em><b>NOTE:</b> You must enter at least one telephone number.</em><br>  The number must include the area code e.g 065553322!</font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Phone (H):</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontacthomephone" />
                </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Mobile:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactcellphone" />
                </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Phone (W):</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="addcontactworkphone" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add contact" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
}

if ($pageID == 0){
    return header('Location: ./');
}
```

?>

Comment: Can you only show us the code we need? Can you break it down into a simpler use case?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs on PDO

> string PDO::lastInsertId ([ string $name = NULL ] ) Returns the ID of
>   the last inserted row, or the last value from a sequence object,
>   depending on the underlying driver. For example, PDO_PGSQL() requires
>   you to specify the name of a sequence object for the name parameter.
>
> Note:
>
> This method may not return a meaningful or consistent result across different PDO drivers, because the underlying database may not even
>   support the notion of auto-increment fields or sequences.

Without seeing the schema there is no way to know but it is possible that you don't have an auto increment field in your database so the insert ID isn't being returned.  In that case your second block of code would fail but the first would succeed.

Comment: My database table to have and auto increment on both tables called id.  The id is the personalinfo table would be used as the contact_id in the contactinfo table which also have an auto incremented id field.  It is almost as if the code don't pick up the last inserted if before trying to execute the query.

`$contact_id = $db->lastInsertId();`

Comment: Have you created an index on the ID field which enforces uniqueness?  It shouldn't be possible to return from the call before the row was inserted so you should have an ID returned if the schema is correct.  Can you add the schema for the table to your question?

Comment: Here is how I create the second table:
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contactinfo` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `streetnumber` int(11) NOT NULL, `streetname` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `suburbname` Varchar(255) NOT NULL, `cityname` varchar(255) NOT NULL, emailhome` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `emailwork` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `omephone` varchar(15) NOT NULL, `cellphone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `workphone` varchar(15) NOT NULL, `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;`

Comment: First table:
'This is the first table:
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `personalinfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `middlename` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;`

Both auto_increment on the id field.'

Comment: I am so blind, I found my mistake.  It fault is in this line of code:
`$stmt2 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO contactinfo (contact_id, streetnumber, streetname, suburbname, cityname, emailhome, emailwork, homephone, cellphone, workphone) VALUES (:addcontact_id, :addcontactstreetnumber, addcontactstreetname, :addcontactsuburb, :addcontactcity, :addcontactemailhome, :addcontactemailwork,:addcontacthomephone, :addcontactcellphone, :addcontactworkphone)');`

Note that there is no ":" in front of the addcontactstreetname.  Thanks for the help.